# Data Analysis communites and learning resources

Tags: references

I took some of the data analysis courses and did a few projects on my own and I feel that I am so far from the community of data analysts and knowing new features when it releases or any new articles, questions, etc.
So I want to know the best resources where I can follow to grow up my knowledge and level up my skills, and also some communities of forums to be more interactive with the people in my field and things like that.
**I appreciate your help so much**

Comment: This is very wide, can you make it more specific?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I mean for example, websites that  I can check daily to follow up the updated contents, like how to use AI in visualization or use Chaptgpt to help analyzing the data, tips & tricks, or any feature that come up that I can use it to make my work more professional.